# HIVE or SQL query to compare pre and post sales for same sample size

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

---

I have a table which has columns as employeeIDs (string), performance rating(int), date(string), along with flag account (string) if subscribed( Account = 'yes' after subscription and 'no' before subscription)

DIFFERENT EMPLOYEES subscribe on different dates,

pre = before subscription
post = after subscription

Need to calculate their sum performance ratings of each pre 4 days  and sum of performance ratings of each post 4 days from the date, when they subscribed.

----------1-----2----3---4--|---4---3---2----1----------

table looks like below( left space between each day just to make it easy to understand)
Table contains rows of transactions for every day for each employee.

> ((code SNIPPET ARE JUST GET TABLE STRUCTURE TO APPEAR CLEAR))

```html
employeeId | performance rating | account | date 
--------------------------------------------------------      
sam            3.2                  no      2013-9-15  
charlie        3.1                  no      2013-9-15  
john           2.1                  no      2013-9-15  

sam            4.1                  yes     2013-9-16  
charlie        5.1                  no      2013-9-16  
john           2.1                  no     2013-9-16  

sam            5.3                  yes     2013-9-17  
charlie        1.4                  no      2013-9-17  
john           6.3                  yes     2013-9-17  

sam            5.3                  yes     2013-9-18  
charlie        1.4                  no      2013-9-18
john           6.3                  yes     2013-9-18

sam            5.3                  yes     2013-9-19
charlie        1.4                  yes      2013-9-19
john           8.3                  yes     2013-9-19

sam            6.3                  yes     2013-9-20
charlie        7.4                  yes      2013-9-20
john           9.3                  yes     2013-9-20
```

>

desired output( numbers are just for sample, NOT calculated ones)

```html
DAY            sum performance rating
pre 1st day    10.0
pre 2nd day    13.9
pre 3rd day    24.9
pre 4th day    12.4       
post 1st day   16.8
post 2nd day   14.6
post 3rd day   17.2
post 4th day   12.8
```

ANy help is appreciated..tried lot of ways but still not able to figure out..

Comment: First, you should decide what database you are using and tag the question appropriately.  I am removing all the database tags.  Feel free to add the one that you are really using.

Comment: I have edited the question..hope its clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can almost do this in standard SQL using subqueries and a non-equijoin:

```
select ta.employeeId,
       avg(case when t2.date < ta.date then t2.rating end) as beforeRating,
       avg(case when t2.date > ta.date then t2.rating end) as afterRating
from (select t.employeeId, min(date) as acctdate
      from table t
      group by t.employeeId
     ) ta join
     table t2
     on ta.employeeId = t2.employeeId and
        t2.date between ta.acctdate - 4 and ta.acctdate + 4 -- Note:  date arithmetic depends on the database
group by ta.employeeId;
```

The only non-standard part is the date arithmetic.  You'll need to express that in the appropriate way for your database.

EDIT:

If you want the results by *day* and not *employee*:

```
select datediff(ta.acctdate, t2.date), avg(t2.rating) as avgrating
from (select t.employeeId, min(date) as acctdate
      from table t
      group by t.employeeId
     ) ta join
     table t2
     on ta.employeeId = t2.employeeId and
        t2.date between ta.acctdate - 4 and ta.acctdate + 4 -- Note:  date arithmetic depends on the database
group by datediff(ta.acctdate, t2.date);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response!!  i haven't showed the whole table due to constraints but i need to calculate sum for each day up to 4, pre and post. To make it more clear, suppose lets take some thing like, required to calculate sum of performance ratings  each week upto 4 weeks on both sides.                                                                                                            -------------4--3--2-1--||------1--2--3--4-------------